# Setting dynamic date variables within a Hive script

Tags: variables, dynamic, hive

I would like to set date variables that calculate a date range based on the current date. Without variables I can use:

```
SELECT name, date 
FROM table1 
WHERE date > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, -10);
```

But I would like to set a variable for the date (we will call this `datevariable`) so I can call it over and over throughout a script. I tried setting a variable like:

```
set datevariable=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,-10);

SELECT name, date 
FROM table1
WHERE date > '${hiveconf:datevariable}';
```

But this throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a dynamic date variable use:

```
set hivevar:datevariable=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,-10);
```

This variable can be used in the following manner:

```
SELECT name, date
FROM table1
WHERE date > CAST(${datevariable} AS STRING);
```